# Disable jQuery click event on child elements

Tags: jquery, events, click, row

I have a table on which I made all table rows to be click-able in relation to the nested links inside them. But I'm trying to disable specific table rows to stop being clicked once they have a class associated with them.

```
<script>
$('.selectable tr').click( function() {
    var productLink = $(this).find("a");

    productLink.attr("target", "_doc");
    window.open(productLink.attr("href"));

    return false;
});

$('.vandut_activ').click( function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    return false;
});
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click the table row with .vandut_activ it still opens a new tab which is empty since it has no link inside to access. How do I stop the click event in this case? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your jQuery version but from jQuery1.6+ you should use `$("input").prop('disabled', true);` for disabling event. Try bellow code(NOT TESTED)

**Option 1:**

```
<script>
$('.selectable tr').click( function() {
    var productLink = $(this).find("a");

    productLink.attr("target", "_doc");
    window.open(productLink.attr("href"));

    return false;
});

$('.vandut_activ').click( function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

**Option 2:**

You can use css property `pointer-events` to disable click event.

```
<script>
$('.selectable tr').click( function() {
    var productLink = $(this).find("a");

    productLink.attr("target", "_doc");
    window.open(productLink.attr("href"));

    return false;
});

$('.vandut_activ').click( function() {
    $(this).css('pointer-events','none');
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have the latest version <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> but still none of your 2 options seem to stop the click function for the specified class. Technically even $('.vandut_activ').click(false); should disable it.

Comment: Try adding $('.vandut_activ').css('pointer-events','none'); manually from browser console and let me know if it disable or not in browser ?

Comment: Have you checked by putting debugger in second click event function that this event if firing or not ?

Comment: Well lol, this worked directly. Strange that it doesn't fire up like the way you prescribed before. Perhaps the first click event activates before the pointer-events can be disabled.

Comment: Yup, but I used Dhiraj method cause it's much faster and flexible for my necessities. Thanks a lot for your time and help, you are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want that click to work on 'tr' which are having 'vandut_activ' class then you can try this,

hope that this is what you are looking for

```
$('.selectable tr:not(.vandut_activ)').on('click', function() {
var productLink = $(this).find("a");

productLink.attr("target", "_doc");
window.open(productLink.attr("href"));

return false;});
```

Comment: Wow.. you are freaking good. It was so simple yet i love to complicate my life so much. This worked better than expected :) Thanks mate!